# Disabling Buttons in Struts 1.2 after any action

Tags: javascript, html, struts

I am completely new to `Struts`, and I am looking for a solution to disable `<forms:button>` while another action executes to avoid double-triple.. execution of same action e.g. adding new record to Database.

So far I tried to use `JavaScript` `getElementById`, but I noticed that there's no `ID` attribute in `<forms:button>`..

Anyone encountered such problem?
Thanks a lot for any advice and help!! :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Comment: @AleksandrM how can I implement this to Struts 1.2? :) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

To set an `id` on a `<button>` use the `styleId` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

either you can add styleId attribute 
OR use document.forms[0]."your button name"."attribute"="value"